# inject `service` inside `run` method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What are the use-cases of `angular.run` method? I have a `heavy` service that consumes `resources` and takes a while to get created before i use it with my `view`.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('heavyService',function($timeout){ 
       this.someAjaxCall=function(){

       } 
});

angular.module('myApp').run(function(heavyService){
      // How can i use my heavyService here and later use in app
});
```

How to inject `service` inside `run` method and later use it in `application`?

Answer (score 2):

Calling order:

1. `app.config()`
2. `app.run()`
3. directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom)
4. `app.controller()`
5. directive's link functions (again if found)

> **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the
>       application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent
>       further system configuration during application run time.

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc#L125)

```
angular.module('myApp').run(['heavyService', function(heavyService) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this? (According to [John Papa's style guide "Route Resolve Promises"](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y081)):

```
// route-config.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/avengers', {
            templateUrl: 'avengers.html',
            controller: 'Avengers',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                moviesPrepService: moviesPrepService
            }
        });
}

function moviesPrepService(movieService) {
    return movieService.getMovies();
}

// avengers.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Avengers', Avengers);

Avengers.$inject = ['moviesPrepService'];
function Avengers(moviesPrepService) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.movies = moviesPrepService.movies;
}
```

Basically what this does it preps the service and gets all the AJAX'ed data before the route resolves, and once that is done, then you have access to the static data in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Run block is there to initialize the values which we want to make available through out application.By injecting service inside run would  only set value of service variables. Whenever any other component would ask for service will get those initialized value (because service are singleton in nature).

**Code**

```
//it acts as initialization block
angular.module('myApp').run(function(heavyService){
     //here you can access service variables and method
     //this variable value has been set before asked from any controller
     heavyService.someVariable = 'Init Value'; 
});
```

In config phase also you can set value of variables which should be initialized(like doing some configuration settings), but the actual thing is config block doesn't have access to the service, they only have access to the `provider` also the `$rootScope` in not available while you are in `config` phase.

The advantage over internalizing values inside run block is they do have access to run `$rootScope` & also you can handle route related event like `$locationchangestart`, `$locationchangesuccess`, `$routechangestart`, etc.

Comment: Cool, calling eavyService.getAjaxCall() inside my run method and setting the response data to heavyService.jsonData = jsonResponse... how will i able to access this data in my controller... without making the ajax call again... Thanks for wonderful explanation

Comment: for that you need to maintain scope variable inside service. that will store data returned from the ajax..then inside your controller you need to inject service first then sync that service variable with scope variable